VW Golf MK2 Engine Advice Wanted
I wanted to know if I could replace a 1.6 8v block with a 1.8 8v block, and if it would be a straight swap, or if any modification would be required.
My current block has a hole in it, so needs replacing but I am not currently in a position to do a complete engine swap.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What years are both of the engines?

The one currently fitted is 1991, and the replacement block would be from the same model vehicle i.e. a Mk2 golf also.
